# Proper way to output AJAX response in module?

Tags: add-on-development, module, ajax

What's the proper way to return an AJAX response within an ExpressionEngine module?

Good ole' `echo "foo"; die();` seems to work but there must be a better way!

I tried the CodeIgniter approach `$this->EE->output->set_output(json_encode($array));`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to return data other than JSON I ended up using the following instead. It's mostly ripped off from the same send_ajax_response function that Bhashkar was kind enough to lead me to. You should probably choose the proper Content-Type (so maybe if it was XML it would be different?).

```
$this->EE->config->item('send_headers') == 'y';
@header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
exit($output);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
$this->EE->output->send_ajax_response($array);
```

for the same purpose.

Comment: This is good for returning JSON data only it seems as I couldn't get it to return just a string via AJAX.